# Is it possible to use $t$ test if the population is not normal and not large?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

The table here -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_statistic -- says that the $t$-test can be used when the following holds:

> (Normal population or $n$ large) and
> $\sigma$  unknown

This seems to imply that if $n$ is small, we cannot use the $t$-test (otherwise the condition $n$ large wouldn't have been mentioned). At the same time, some other sources say that we can and should use $t$-test when the '$n<30$' or just anytime that we do not know $\sigma$ For the latter claim, see e.g. the table [here](https://vitalflux.com/when-to-use-z-test-vs-t-test-differences-examples/). For the former, see [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistics/Testing_Data/t-tests#:%7E:text=A%20small%20sample%20is%20generally,single%20mean%20can%20be%20used.), which says:

> The t-test is the small sample analog of the z test which is suitable for large samples. A small sample is generally regarded as one of size n<30.
> A t-test is necessary for small samples because their distributions are not normal.

So, Wikipedia contradicts some of the other sources. My question is: if the population is not normal and $n$ is not large, is it possible or not to use the $t$-test?

Comment: The  (non-Wikipedia) source you linked has the disclaimer that what it writes is disputed. Indeed, there is no justification, that I know of to use a t-test without believing the sample mean is approximately normal. Also, this is not a question about mathematics, it should be asked on cross-validated.

Comment: Three issues: The distinction between the $z$-test and $t$-test is whether you know the standard error  of what you are testing or need to estimate it from the sample: it is the effect of errors when estimating the variance which lead to the $t$ distribution.  Both assume that the sample mean has a normal distribution, or is close enough to normal not to make a substantial difference; whether this is reasonable with your sample size will depend on the underlying distribution.  The $>30$ point is a holdover from printed statistical tables; the two distributions are further apart for small $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The t-distribution is only a correct model when you calculate the T-statistic from a sample from a normally distributed population -- that was the assumption that was used to derive the distribution in the first place.

For large samples, the sample mean will (almost) behave as if it were drawn from a normal distribution -- you'll see that the percentiles provided by the t-distribution will be very close to the normal distribution percentiles for n>30 from a normal distribution.

That being said, the t-test is known to be [robust to deviations of normality](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Esnijders/SM_robustness.pdf)(see starting on p.19) unless you have a **small sample** from a **very non-normal population** (i.e., "fat-tailed": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution).

Just like with any dataset, you should run some normality tests and also just look at a histogram to gauge if there is substantial skew or kurtosis.